# Hive insert creating different parquet that Spark insert

Tags: pyspark, hive, parquet, parquet-mr

I am using hdp 2.6.5.0-292.

In this environment Data is getting processed using Hive as well as pyspark.

Insert using SQL such as:

```
INSERT INTO table PARTITION(run_date='{run_date}') (...)  VALUES(...)
```

is creating parquet 1.8.1, while pyspark dataframe insert into:

```
[df.write.mode("append").insertInto(table)]
```

is giving 1.6.0.

How can we make both 1.8.1?

```
creator:          parquet-mr version 1.8.1 (build 4aba4dae7bb0d4edbcf7923ae1339f28fd3f7fcf)
creator:          parquet-mr version 1.6.0 (build 6aa21f8776625b5fa6b18059cfebe7549f2e00cb)
```

Please help to fix this issue.

This is what my show create table looks like:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc.xyz(
> ...)
> PARTITIONED BY (
> run_date string)
> ROW FORMAT SERDE
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
> STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
> OUTPUTFORMAT
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
> LOCATION
> 'hdfs://...'
> TBLPROPERTIES (
> 'spark.sql.create.version'='2.2 or prior',
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='1',
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{...}',
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='run_date',
> 'transient_lastDdlTime'='1608546154')